# MCU + RFID tag that reads and writes RFID messages

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

I would like your input on choosing a proper RFID tag simulator chip.

I'm looking for an MCU + RFID tag setup that will allow me to receive commands and answer them (specifically, mifare commands).

The typical use case is:
1. MCU receives command from antenna and I reach a handler in the code with the proper command received.
2. I command the MCU to transmit a speific answer. The answer sgould be exactly what I command, without any additional CRC or what not.

Also, it would be very, very helpful if the identification process will not be done automatically, but I get alerted on each command received and choose if and how to reply to it.

Can you recommend me a product that does this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the TI TRF7970 is a good decision for that. You can put this Reader chip into transparent mode which allows you full control of the sending and receiving of frames. If this is not necessary you can let also the Reader chip doing the frame handling and you are doing only the data interpretation of the MCU.
The MCU should be a fast cpu because the latency of processing commands should be very short. (depending on which layer you wanna work)

best regards

Comment: Thank you!I will look into it :)